# How can I add multiple inline style in body?

Tags: html, css, angular, inline

In my Angular application body, I am trying to add multiple INLINE body styles. I was able to add background image, but adding another inline style breaks the code

```
<body style=background-image:url("https://p0.pikrepo.com/preview/122/34/concrete-road-between-mountains.jpg")>
  <app-root>
</app-root>
</body>
```

Comment: wrap the  value in double quotes i.e. `style="background-image:url() color:red"`. Within the double quotes, different style attributes are separated by space

Comment: Adding this breaks the code, background image disappears `<body style="background-image:url("https://p0.pikrepo.com/preview/122/34/concrete-road-between-mountains.jpg") background="cover"">
"
`

Comment: it will be `background-size:cover`. and value of url, wrap that in single quote i.e. `"background-image:url('https://...') background:cover"`

Comment: This did not work `<body style="background-image:url('https://p0.pikrepo.com/preview/122/34/concrete-road-between-mountains.jpg') background-size="cover"">
`

Comment: This worked`<body style="background-image:url('https://p0.pikrepo.com/preview/122/34/concrete-road-between-mountains.jpg'); background-size:cover">
` Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following method and any properties with; Separate.

```html
<body style="background-image:url('https://p0.pikrepo.com/preview/122/34/concrete-road-between-mountains.jpg'); color:#fff;">
```